# How to redirect action=register link on the lostpassword page to a different link?

Tags: redirect, user-registration, password

I have a specific wordpress registration page where I have a new user complete their registration form.  However, if someone clicks on the "forgot password" link in the login section of my site and then clicks on register, they'll be able to register for the site without going through the normal registation form.  How can I redirect the wp-login.php?action=register page to sample.com/register ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook into `login_form_register` and throw people to your registration page with `wp_redirect`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'login_form_register', 'wpse45134_catch_register' );
/**
 * Redirects visitors to `wp-login.php?action=register` to 
 * `site.com/register`
 */
function wpse45134_catch_register()
{
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/register' ) );
    exit(); // always call `exit()` after `wp_redirect`
}
```

You can also hide the "register" link on that page by hijacking the `user_can_register` option on the login page.  Hook into `login_form_lostpassword` and `login_form_retrievepassword`, from there add a filter to `pre_option_users_can_register`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'login_form_lostpassword', 'wpse45134_filter_option' );
add_action( 'login_form_retrievepassword', 'wpse45134_filter_option' );
/**
 * Simple wrapper around a call to add_filter to make sure we only
 * filter an option on the login page.
 */
function wpse45134_filter_option()
{
    // use __return_zero because pre_option_{$opt} checks
    // against `false`
    add_filter( 'pre_option_users_can_register', '__return_zero' );
}
```

As a [plugin](https://gist.github.com/2012290).

Comment: Thanks Christopher!  Just one question, how do I implement this as a plugin?  I've never created a wp plugin before but if you have a link for direction, etc. I'm comfortable with code and such

Comment: You would just copy and paste the code above into a single PHP file, put in the plugin header (http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers), drop the PHP file into your `wp-content/plugins` directory.  Here is the complete thing as a plugin https://gist.github.com/2012290